# Application can't load photos from Photo Library on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator, xcode8.2

I am facing problem in loading photos on simulator but it is working on devices. Even it is working on other mac. I have added the *NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription* key into the plist file. But the permission message is not loading while I am going to access the photo library.

Instead I am getting the following scenario on simulator:

[image]

I have also checked the settings on simulator and my app is not showing on Photos privacy:

[image]

Comment: brother open your setting and allow to your application

Comment: @makboney : Why don't you directly go settings -> privacy -> camera and allow access from there?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya  thank you for your reply but unfortunately my app is not showing in privacy settings. please see second screenshot

Comment: @Poles thank you for your reply, I need to access photo library and added permission key into plist file. I did the same like you mentioned but my app is not showing there. please see second screenshot

Comment: IF you dont mind then one more solution i want to suggest you . just uninstall app and then clean your project and build it and then check it that your device ask you for permission or not ?

Comment: @makboney : Himanshu is right. Follow his suggestions. If that doesn't solve the problem please reset simulator or try the app in a real ios 10 device.

Comment: @makboney Is your application Info.plist file contains a key: "CFBundleDisplayName" ?

Comment: @ Dipankar Das thank you for your reply. I have added that key and set $(PRODUCT_NAME) as value but still same :(

Comment: @makboney Is your Xcode in your Applications folder ?

Comment: @ Dipankar Das thanks a lot, you saved me...please move your comment to answer section, I will accept it so that other can take advantages :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to add permission 
Please read this link to load photos in iOS 10

https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/09/infoplist-privacy-settings-in-ios-10.html

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have already added that NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key into the plist, mentioned in my question. It is woking on device actually but not in simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give permission to your app to access photos. For this you need to do following steps:

1. Open settings in your simulator
2. Look for your App name and then tap on it.
3. Then turn on the switch to access photo's.

Comment: when you are tapping to gallery button on app... is it asked to access the gallery?

Comment: no, that permission alert isn't showing at that time :(

Comment: ohh... it should show... can you pleaes uninstall the app and try to run it again...

Comment: tried several times, its actually working on of my friend's mac :(

Comment: try by removing derived data from your system.... may be it helps you...

Comment: got the problem, my xcode was not in Application folder. moved it to Application folder and now it is working

Comment: Great man..... i keep this thing in my mind if, in future i face this kind of issue... :)